# How do I add a box shadow to a new component

Tags: javascript

I am making a sort of flappy bird game and have made the pillars as `new components` that appear at different lengths according to `Math.random()`. But even though I can change the colors of these pillars i really want to add a box-shadow on them, just to make it look cool. It's not really necessary. So, if anyone could let me know if I can even add a box-shadow to a component or not would be helpful as well.
Here's the code for the pillars if you want to have a look:

```
    if (myGameArea.frameNo == 1 || everyinterval(150)) {
        x = myGameArea.canvas.width;
        minHeight = 60;
        maxHeight = 100;
        height = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxHeight-minHeight+1)+minHeight);
        minGap = 60;
        maxGap = 200;
        gap = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxGap-minGap+1)+minGap);
        myObstacles.push(new component(10, height, "lightgray", x, 0));
        myObstacles.push(new component(10, x - height - gap, "gray", x, height + gap, "box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px white;")); // on black background
    }
```

Comment: Was the answer below what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are creating these with js and not HTML/CSS you’ll want to use `shadowColor` `shadowOffsetX` `shadowOffsetY` `shadowBlur`

Reference https://www.w3resource.com/html5-canvas/html5-canvas-shadow.php

Comment: Yes it did. Thank you.